# How to find which React Native module is causing a crash

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native app.  It works well most of the time, but in our automated error detection framework, I can see some users infrequently run into a crash in React Native.  There is a `SIGABRT` and a bunch of lines like this in the stack trace:

```
facebook::react::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker
```

I'm reasonably confident that the issue isn't directly in my application's code -- not only is the stacktrace all React Native stuff, but one of my coworkers triggered the error right after logging in a couple times, and I've never triggered this error myself despite testing the login flow many times.

Other websites make it seem like the error might actually be in a native module (but not React Native itself), but I wasn't able to figure out how to debug which native module it could be (the error doesn't happen often enough to easily just try disabling native modules one by one or anything like that).

Is there a way to get more information about what is actually causing a crash when the crash is in native code?

Thanks!